# How to extract log using bash script between a date / time and another

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, logfile

have a 3 logfiles and need to extract via bash a period, however it does not identify the file as date / time.
Can anyone help me with how would a script using sed or awk or even grep get a log from YYYY / MM / DD HH: MM: ss to YYYY / MM / DD HH: MM: ss?

My logs files is generated something like this:

```
    2019-06-04-06.48.05.040000  INFO v65a8fe79:16a8d792e10:-d37:10.150.100.000 66.200.83.195 |36983 RD8jrq1limntMPACJ4iRx-D
    2019-06-04-07.38.03.145000  INFO 2d5bb9b6:16a8d794bd9:-ae9:10.150.100.000 200.200.87.8 |37027 fje7hxh7yKCGZcEQOnPOafQ 
    2019-06-04-07.38.09.966000  INFO 65a8fe79:16a8d792e10:-d36:10.150.100.000 200.200.87.8 |37029 3hesLFH1cySQ1so0YSmShbV    
    2019-06-04-07.38.09.966000  INFO 2d5bb9b6:16a8d794bd9:-ae8:10.150.100.000 200.200.87.8 |37028 SykkGWSrAXh8yUG
```

and the others have this format:

```
2019-06-05 00:28:50,548 DEBUG [site.aq.application.object.context.DataContextFactoryImpl] - [Criado o DataContext com -389:192.193.10.250]
2019-06-05 00:28:50,550 INFO [site.aq.application.object.context.DataContextFactoryImpl] - [CacheableRegraUserAgentService:  countFail=8, matchRate=0.6]
2019-06-05 00:28:50,554 DEBUG [site.aq.application.object.context.DataContextFactoryImpl] - [Liberado o dataContext com ID 2d5bb9b6:16a8d794bd9:-389:192.193.46.200]
2019-06-05 07:20:04,628 DEBUG [site.aq.application.object.context.DataContextFactoryImpl] - [Criado o DataContext com ID65a8fe79:16a8d792e10:-5e8:192.300.46.200]
```

I am begnner and with exemple  search I do this:

I try write this:

Create the file "lista-log.awk"

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {
    starttime = mktime(starttime)
    endtime = mktime(endtime)
}

func in_range(n, start, end) {
    return start <= n && n < end
}

match($0, /^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})\s/, m) && 
    in_range(mktime(m[1] " " m[2] " " m[3] " 00 00 00"), starttime, endtime)
```

and on promtp I write for example:

```
./lista-log.awk -v starttime='2019 06 05 00 00 00' -v endtime='2019 06 05 04 39 00' arquivo.log.txt
```

but I think that it's as if he does not understand that this is an hour/date, why don't retorn nothing

Comment: what do yo mean by "it  does not identify date"; who is 'it'? That said, what did you try?

Comment: You might be able to base something on my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/102531/1293).

Comment: What do you mean by "it's as if he does not understand that this is an hour / date"; who/what is "he"? It sounds like you tried something but didn't get the results you expected - [edit] your question to show us what you tried, what you expected, what you got, and describe the problem.

Comment: Now I have described better everything I have done and the problem I am facing. Anyone who can help will thank me very much.

Answer (score 3):

The nice thing you have is that your date-time is a sortable format. So all you need to do is write the following awk line:

```
awk -v tStart="2019-05-31-01.02.03.000000" -v tEnd="2019-06-01-21.02.03.000000" \
    '($1 >= tStart) && ($1 < tEnd)' file
```

Comment: You don't need the `.000000`s as it's a string comparison and so will be done 1 char at a time starting from the front of each string.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but I'm a beginner and when I type this at the command prompt it does not return anything.
I put it like this:
awk -v tStart = "2019-06-05-00.28.50.0000" -v tEnd = "2019-06-05-04.00.00.0000" \ '($ 1> = tStart) && ($ 1 <tEnd)' filelogs.txt >> logs2.txt
that's right?

Comment: There are a lot of spaces in the command you showed just now. These spaces should not be there! Eg. `tStart = "2019-06-05-00.28.50.000000"` should read `tStart="2019-06-05-00.28.50.000000"`, also `$ 1` should be `$1`

Comment: Hello friend, now it was, however I just added a "p" after the bar, it looked like this:
`awk -v tStart = "2019-06-06-07.00.00" -v tEnd = "2019-06-06-08.10.00" \p '($1> = tStart) && ($1 <tEnd)' file.log .txt >> logright.txt `
however facing the new scenario I changed the question a bit because I saw that some logs work with another date pattern and in that case? how can I do to put something generic and it search? can you help me?

Comment: @kvantour please how I use if hour format is this "2019-06-05 00:00:50"? can you help me?